# Launch angle required to hit coordinate (x,y) with air resistance

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, physics, parametric

[Finding Angle of Elevation to hit X, Y](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83206/finding-angle-of-elevation-to-hit-x-y) and [Wikipedia Angle required to hit coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Angle_required_to_hit_coordinate_.28x.2Cy.29) work, but don't calculate air resistance.

Is there a way to find the launch angle of a projectile required to hit x,y with air resistance?

Comment: I would guess that the non-linearities (if/when present - depends on how you model air resistance) make closed form solutions of the range as a function of the angle either non-existent or unusable. Numerical methods are probably needed. Once you are happy with those then just run it for a dense set of selected angles, and interpolate. Somebody has probably done a lot of work on this (the military has use for such look-up-tables). You may have better luck at Physics.SE.

Comment: Much classified work on this going back to World War Two, now widely available. Difficult in general. Also heavily dependent on the nature of the object and spin.

Comment: @Jyrki, That looks like it would be the easiest way to do it. I'll give it a shot (pun intended).

Comment: IIRC the Germans noticed already in WWI that with the really big guns you get better range with launch angles up to $55$ degrees. A high arc $\implies$ lower air density $\implies$ less drag when high up. My limited experience tells that with small guns, 3-6 inch shells with initial launch velocity about Mach 2, this effect is not prevalent. We also have: Longer flight time $\implies$ more drag. The two effects are competing.